# Is every compact totally ordered space homeomorphic to a subset of $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, order-theory

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a totally ordered set such that, equipped with the order topology, $X$ is compact. Is then $X$ homeomorphic to a closed subset $A \subseteq [0,1]$?

A way to ask this question colloquially: Can we put points together in a compact way such that they are "denser" than the reals? I feel the answer is no but I lack a proper counterexample.

Comment: [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Ordinal_space) one example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No: the [closed long ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) is a counterexample. It is a totally ordered set with the order topology, it is compact, and it is not metrizable. Another, perhaps easier, counterexample is the [lexicographically ordered square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square), i.e., $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the lexicographic order topology. This is compact, but

$$\big\{\{x\}\times(0,1):x\in[0,1]\big\}$$

is an uncountable, pairwise disjoint family of open sets, something that cannot exist in the separable space $[0,1]$.

Comment: Could you please explain, why these spaces are compact?

Comment: @Zardo: In both cases the linear order is complete and has endpoints; this automatically implies that the order topology is compact.

Comment: OK, I get that in the first example, but in the second: Why arent the $\{x\}\times[0,1]$ open sets which would form an open cover without finite subcover?

Comment: Nevermind I got it! Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @Zardo: You’re welcome!

Comment: This is even connected, isn't it?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, both spaces are, since the linear orders are complete and dense.

Comment: So $[0,1]\times[0,1)$ with the lexicographic order is not connected, right? Because it's not complete ($\{0\}\times[0,1)$ does not have a least upper bound).

Comment: @Stefan: Correct: $\{0\}\times[0,1)$ is clopen in that space.

Comment: Thanks :-) By *dense* you mean that for all $a<b$ there is a $c$ with $a<c<b$, right. And a LOTS is connected if and only if it's complete and dense?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, and yes. :-)